# Feed Pagination PHP Logic

Tags: php, pagination

Not sure if somone can help with this but have tried various things
and don't seem to be able to resolve it. After searching for quite a 
bit and not finding anything I managed to put a crude temporary fix in 
place but that works in a roundabout way and is not ideal.

I am trying to display the output of a feed and have example code that paginates
the results.

The example code pretty much works and displays pages as it should but
there are two problems:

1) If I set the number of items per page to be as an example 10 - if the
feed has 10 or less items in then it doesn't display anything. If there are
for instance five items in the feed then I would need to set the number of
results per page to 4 so that it would create two pages and then it would
display. If I set it to display 5 or 10 then nothing is shown.

2) This may be connected to the above but if there are 100 items in the
feed and I set the number of items per page to be 10 then it should create
10 pages. What actually happens is that it creates 11 - the 11th page is
blank.

Here is the code in full from the example (apologies for the length):

```
<html>
<?php
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$numItems = '~~~NumberOfFeedItems~~~';

$onePage = 1;
$startNumber = 0;
if ($numItems > $itemsPerPage) {
  $onePage = 0;
  // Check for requested starting position
  if (isset($_REQUEST['ItemNumber'])) {
    $startNumber = $_REQUEST['ItemNumber'];
  }

  // Validate starting position
  if ($startNumber > $numItems) {
    $startNumber = 0;
  }
}

$pageString = '';
// Create the list of pages, if needed
if ($onePage == 0) {
  $Qparts = Array();
  $parts = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  if (count($parts) > 0) {
    foreach ($parts as $value) {
      if (substr($value, 0, 10) != 'ItemNumber') {
        $Qparts[] = $value;
      }
    }
    if (count($Qparts) == 0) {
      $Qstring = '';
    }
    elseif (count($Qparts) == 1) {
      $Qstring = $Qparts[0].'&amp;';
    } else {
      $Qstring = implode('&amp;', $Qparts).'&amp;';
    }
  }

  //
  // Previous Page
  $pageString = '<strong>';
  if ($startNumber > 0) {
    $newStartIndex = $startNumber - $itemsPerPage;
    if ($newStartIndex < 0) {
      $newStartIndex = 0;
    }
    $pageString .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$Qstring.'ItemNumber='.$newStartIndex.'">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  }

  //
  // The jump to page markers
  if ($numItems > $itemsPerPage) {
    $tempPages = (int)(($numItems / $itemsPerPage) + 1);
    $x = 1;
    if ($tempPages > 12) {
      // There are too many pages to fit across
      if ((($startNumber+1)/10) > 7) {
        $pageString .= '...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $x = 1 + (int)(($startNumber+1)/10) - 6;
      }
    }

    for ($y = 0; $x <= $tempPages; $x++, $y++) {
      $tempStart = ($itemsPerPage * ($x - 1));
      if (($tempStart <= $startNumber) && ($startNumber < ($tempStart + $itemsPerPage))) {
        $pageString .= $x.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
      } else {
        $pageString .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$Qstring.'ItemNumber='.$tempStart.'">'.$x.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
      }
      if ($y >= 12) {
        $pageString .= '...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //
  // Next Page
  if ($startNumber + $itemsPerPage <= $numItems) {
    $pageString .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$Qstring.'ItemNumber='.($startNumber + $itemsPerPage).'">Next</a>';
  }
  $pageString .= '</strong>';
}

?>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>~~~FeedTitle~~~</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>~~~FeedTitle~~~</h1>
    <p>~~~FeedDescription~~~</p>
    <hr>
<?php
echo $pageString."<br />\n";
$x = 0;
?>
    <table width="100%">
      ~~~BeginItemsRecord~~~
<?php
if ($onePage == 0) {
  if (($startNumber <= $x) && ($x < $startNumber+$itemsPerPage)) {
?>
      <tr><td>~~~ItemPubShortDate~~~ ~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~</td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="~~~ItemLink~~~">~~~ItemTitle~~~</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>~~~ItemDescription~~~</td></tr>
      <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<?php
  }
  $x++;
}
?>
      ~~~EndItemsRecord~~~
    </table>
<?php
echo $pageString."<br />\n";
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know it can be difficult to look through the amount of coding above and spot anything
so it's a bit of a long shot I know.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code.

The first you just show pages if you have more feeds than needed for one page!
If you have lmore than 1 page you safe `$onePage = 0` but in the end you just output in this case not the other:

```
<?php
if ($onePage == 0) {
  if (($startNumber <= $x) && ($x < $startNumber+$itemsPerPage)) {
?>
      <tr><td>~~~ItemPubShortDate~~~ ~~~ItemPubShortTime~~~</td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="~~~ItemLink~~~">~~~ItemTitle~~~</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>~~~ItemDescription~~~</td></tr>
      <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<?php
  }
  $x++;
}
// Here the else is missing!
?>
```

Your second problem that in case of 100 items it will create 11 pages is connected to this:

```
// Next Page
if($startNumber + $itemsPerPage <= $numItems) {
    $pageString .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$Qstring.'ItemNumber='.($startNumber + $itemsPerPage).'">Next</a>';
}
```

if you have 100 items 10 feeds per page, and show the 10th page! You're `$startNumber` is 90, cause you start with an 0 based index. So `$startNumber + $itemsPerPage` is exactly 100 so its exactly your amount of feeds `$numItems` which is also 100.

So replace the `<=` with `<`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to reply - took a little while to get the else statement right. Many thanks for taking the time to reply - the first one was sorted straight away and the second one the issue was in a couple of places but your answer was right and I changed it in those places too. Your help was very much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah no problem, it seems to be easyier to find these kinds of errors in code of others I guess.